# How to select null values in String format data after joining the Kstreams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I have performed join operations on two kstreams which consists of avro format data and then my key is of type Integer and values are of type string. The output is like this:

```
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 1, {"id": 1, "name": "john", "age": 26}/{"id":1, "name": "d", "age": 67}
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 2, {"id": 2, "name": "jane", "age": 24}/{"id": 2, "name": "e", "age": 78}
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 3, {"id": 3, "name": "julia", "age": 25}/{"id": 3, "name": "h", "age": 12}
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 4, {"id": 4, "name": "jamie", "age": 22}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 5, {"id": 5, "name": "jenny", "age": 27}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 6, {"id": 6, "name": "kishore", "age": 27}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 7, {"id": 7, "name": "purna", "age": 27}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 8, {"id": 8, "name": "xxx", "age": 10}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 9, {"id": 9, "name": "yyy", "age": 10}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 10, {"id": 10, "name": "zzz", "age": 10}/null
```

Now i want to filter out values where there is null at the end. my expected output should be like:

```
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 4, {"id": 4, "name": "jamie", "age": 22}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 5, {"id": 5, "name": "jenny", "age": 27}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 6, {"id": 6, "name": "kishore", "age": 27}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 7, {"id": 7, "name": "purna", "age": 27}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 8, {"id": 8, "name": "xxx", "age": 10}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 9, {"id": 9, "name": "yyy", "age": 10}/null
[KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000016]: 10, {"id": 10, "name": "zzz", "age": 10}/null
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, remove null value

```
    KStream<Long, String> stream = streamsBuilder
        .stream("TOPIC1", Consumed.with(Long(), Serdes.String()))
        .filter((k, v) -> v != null);

    KStream<Long, String> stream2 = streamsBuilder
        .stream("TOPIC2", Consumed.with(Long(), Serdes.String()))
        .filter((k, v) -> v != null);

    stream.join(stream2, (value1, value2) -> value1 + "/" + value2, JoinWindows.of(1000));
```

Comment: I got that null values after performing join operation. In my original data i don't have any null values.

Comment: Mayby `filter((k, v) -> v.endWith("/null"))` ?

Comment: @SujithaChinnu  is it right 'join'?  (not left join)    / javadoc : https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#join-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueJoiner-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.JoinWindows-